# login screen popup close button showing only of scroll in some small screen device

Tags: html, css, angular, ionic-framework

This is my Login Screen using based on https://github.com/gihan667/ionic-login-ui

```
  <ion-content class="ion-padding" mode="ios">
      <div class="title">
        <h4>Login</h4>
        <p>Lets get started</p>
      </div>
    
      <form [formGroup]="credentials">
        <ion-list lines="none">
          
          <ion-item>
          <ion-input placeholder="Username" formControlName="userName" class="primary-input"></ion-input>
          </ion-item>
    
          <ion-item>
          
            <ion-input [type]="showPsw===true ? 'text': 'password'"  placeholder="Password" formControlName="password" autocomplete="off"  class="primary-input"> 
            </ion-input>
              
    
        </ion-item>
       
        </ion-list>
          
        <ion-button expand="block" (click)="!isSubmitted && login()" >LOGIN</ion-button>
        
      <div class="ion-margin-top ion-text-center"> <a (click)="dismiss()">Close</a>
        
      </div>
    </form>
    
    </ion-content>
```

SCSS file

```
.title {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.title h4 {
  color: var(--ion-color-primary);
}

.title p {
  margin-top: 0 !important;
  color: #999999;
  font-size: small;
}

.forget a {
  font-size: small !important;
}


ion-item {
  margin-bottom: 6px;
  background: transparent;
  border: 1px solid #eac402;
  --highlight-height: 0px;
  --highlight-color-valid: #eac402;
  --highlight-color-focused: #eac402;
  --highlight-color-invalid: #eac402;
}
```

In global.scss file

```
.login-modal .modal-wrapper {
    height: 45%;
    top: 55%;
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
}
```

EDIT: when login button in  welcome screen clicked  login page showing in modal below is code for the same..

```
<ion-button expand="block" class="ion-margin-top" (click)="login()"  color="white">LOGIN</ion-button>



 constructor(
    public modalCtrl: ModalController,public authService:AuthenticationService
  ) { }

  async login() {
        const modal = await this.modalCtrl.create({
          component: LoginPage,
          animated: true,
          mode: 'ios',         
          cssClass: 'login-modal',
        })
    
        return await modal.present();
      }
```

The Above login page showing in modal. In all big screen devices it showing corecltly.

But less than 6 inch devices **close button** showing with scroll..Please let me know how to prevent scroll in small devices.Thanks

[image: Screen shot of Login page]

Comment: I don't see any close button in the screenshot can you make that in a stackblitz or codesandbox

Comment: Close button is in  below login button..it is only a tag...all code are available in question ..I don't no how to use stackbliz..please help

Comment: is that `ion-modal` ?

Comment: Yes ..ita ion modal controller

Comment: ok wait I'll be back ASAP

Comment: set more height for the `ion-modal`

Comment: I have updated  in question..pls check ..

Comment: can you fork your code up in here - https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-v4-angular-modal

Comment: Just because you specified `height: 45%`, does not necessarily mean the content will fit into whatever actual height this results in - it might simply overflow.

Comment: @CBroe  i dont much in css..can you please help me

Comment: Position the element from `bottom: 0` instead, and give it a `min-height` instead of a height ...? Then the upper edge of the element would move up above the 55% mark, if the height of its content required that.

Comment: @CBroe ca u pls answer

Comment: Did I not just suggest something to try?

Comment: @Viira  i dont no how to use stack bliz ..but i have updated welcome code related code in the question.....i will try to update in stackbliz.

Comment: @CBroe it dooes not work

Comment: @vira am using this template in github https://github.com/gihan667/ionic-login-ui

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```css
@media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .login-modal .modal-wrapper {
    overflow: hidden !important;
  }
}
```

Comment: i dont no much about  css ..can u pls update only screen and ? how to check this

Comment: Sorry i mean
@media only screen ...

The only keyword prevents older browsers that do not support media queries with media features from applying the specified styles

Comment: this  does not work

Answer (score 0):

try increasing the height and also modify the positioning top to lesser value. something like :

```
    .login-modal{
          height: 60%;
          top: 40%;
          position: absolute;
          display: block;
          border-radius: 20px 20px 0 0;
      }
```

also try learning bootstrap/ using material modules for css they are usually designed to support multiple viewports